# value of (a+b-c)(a-b+c)(b+c-a) in terms of a,b and c

Tags: linear-algebra

> what is the value of **(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(b+c-a)**?
>    I have tried this in a problem and it turns out to be (a+b+c)... is it correct?

Comment: How could it be $a+b+c$? If $a=b=c$ it is $a^3$, not $3a$.

Comment: We need more contexts.

Comment: $(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)= -(a^3+b^3+c^3)+ (a^2b+ab^2+b^2c+bc^2+c^2a+ca^2)-2abc$ ... quite different from $a+b+c$ ... but there will be exceptional values of $a,b,c$ that will cause these two quantities to be equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(x-2a)(x-2b)(x-2c)=x^3-2(a+b+c)x^2+4(ab+ac+bc)x-8abc$. Then the value you want is:

$$f(a+b+c)=-(a+b+c)^3+4(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)-8abc$$